# Any way to retrieve response url from process_links function with Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to access the response (url as condition) from a `process_links` function so I can rewrite the URL. Is there any way to do this? Currently, I get the error: process_links() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

```
class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider_1'
    allowed_domains = 'domain.com',
    start_urls = (
        'http://domain.com/new/1.html?content=image',
        'http://domain.com/new/1.html?content=video',
    )

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]')), callback='parse_page', process_links='process_links', follow=True)
    ]

def process_links(self, links, resp):
    for link in links:
        if 'content=photo' in resp.url:
            link.url = "%s?content=photo" % link.url
        else:
            link.url = "%s?content=video" % link.url
    return links
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
def process_links(self, links, resp):
```

to

```
def process_links(self, links):
```

You expect to receive the response in your function, but Scrapy give you just the links.

Maybe something like that could be what you want:

```
rules = [
  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('content=photo'), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]')), callback='parse_page', process_links='process_photo_links', follow=True),
  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]')), callback='parse_page', process_links='process_video_links', follow=True),
]

def process_photo_links(self, links, resp):
    for link in links:
        link.url = "%s?content=photo" % link.url
    return links

def process_video_links(self, links, resp):
    for link in links:
        link.url = "%s?content=video" % link.url
    return links
```

**Update after comment:**

Yes, Scrapy does pass the response to process_links.
You could simple ignore the rules and generate the request your self:

```
def parse_page(self, response):

    ...

    links = LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]')).extract_links(response)

    for link in links:
        if 'content=photo' in response.url:
            link.url = "%s?content=photo" % link.url
        else:
            link.url = "%s?content=video" % link.url

        yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: the problem is that none of the links extracted from the page contain `content=*`, this is why I'm trying to append it. I'm trying to detect it from the response URL (previously rewritten urls). Doesn't seem that there is any way for scrapy to pass the response to process_links. I might be out of luck.

Comment: Seems like LinkExtractor will not work in this scenario but the concept makes sense.
`AttributeError: 'LxmlLinkExtractor' object has no attribute 'extract'`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It should be `extract_links`